# Shunt ohmmeter statement

Tags: circuit-analysis, instrumentation

Please refer to [this link](http://mysya01.files.wordpress.com/2012/04/ohmmeter.pdf) On page 4 there is a statement "Further, at half deflection, current through \$R_h\$ is equal to sum of the currents through \$R_{sh}\$ and \$R_{m}\$". How has this statement come? Can anyone prove this statement? I did not understand how this statement has come?

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be proven because it's not true.

If Rh = Rsh || Rm then the deflection will be \$ \frac {R1 + Rsh||Rm}{2R1 + Rsh || Rm}\$

If R1 >> Rsh||Rm then the deflection will be about 0.5.

Comment: It is given in my book of mms anand instrumentation also. It is true. But how I didnt know

Comment: Ass-U-Me that the current through R1 is constant then you get the result you want. But it isn't. The difference might be a few percent typically.